# Props object what is the meaning of passing children to the component from React official documentation

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was reading about props in

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

It says

```
const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;
```

> "When React sees an element representing a user-defined component, it
> passes JSX attributes and children to this component as a single
> object. We call this object “props”."

I didn't under "...children to this component.." where are children getting passed here ?

Comment: I apologize for the misstart on my answer yesterday (was in a hurry and began being downvoted whilst editing, so deleted until I could finish the research and reconvene). Your question turned out to be more astute than at first I thought, and I ended up being somewhat surprised by what I found.  I trust the revised answer is what you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming u want to know what happens to `children` prop, when u use component like this,

```
<Welcome name="Sara" />;
```

the `children` will be `null` in this case.

This example might be helpful,

```js
function Welcome({name, children}) {
  console.log(children)

  return <div>
    <h3>Hey guys, My name is {name}</h3>
    
    childrens passed to this Component are/is,
    <pre>
      {JSON.stringify(children)}
    </pre>
  </div>
}

function App() {
  return <main>
    <Welcome name="Sara" />
    <hr />
    <Welcome name="Sara">
      lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </Welcome>
    <hr />
    {/* including it because this feels weird to me */}
    <Welcome name="Sara" children={'lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'} />
  </main>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a good answer and it is certainly not worthy of The Checkmark. Please improve this answer, or delete it.

Comment: @crashwap can you please revisit edited answer and let me know your thoughts ?

Answer (score -1):

In your question `name="Sara"` are the children. However, the way the sentence is written, the phrase *and children to this component* is a general statement and might not apply to the example given.

It is commonly understood that children are nested Components. However:

> If you take a look at the React docs you will see it says that “children are an opaque data structure”. What they are essentially telling us is that props.children can be any type, such as an array, a function, an object, etc. Since you can pass anything, you can never know for sure.

I had always thought of children as other Components, parts of Components, and/or JSX/HTML elements that are passed into a Component. I was wrong.

Props, as we know, are those things that are passed into a Component, and include variables (usually objects), functions and/or other HTML/JSX elements and Components.

Ditto with children.

Props is the *methodology* by which the children are passed into the Component. We often refer to things passed in via Props as ... props. In reality, they are children.

*In America there is a brand of nose tissue called Kleenex. I don't know if it was the first brand or merely the most popular brand, but today it is more common to ask for a Kleenex than to ask for a tissue. This same appears to be true for the term Props.*

#### References:

https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/

https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf

https://kolosek.com/react-props-basic/